# Ruby: creating a simple application in Qt

Tags: ruby, user-interface, qt, qtruby

I'm trying to create a simple application, written in Ruby via Qt. I designed a form (MainForm) in a Qt Designer and translated it via `rbuic4` to the Ruby code representation. The pure untouched result has four methods, and looks like this:

```
=begin
** Form generated from reading ui file 'stackover.ui'
**
** Created: Р’С‚ 24. РЅРѕСЏ 21:15:02 2009
**      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.3.1
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling ui file!
=end

class Ui_MainWindow
    attr_reader :centralwidget
    attr_reader :pushButton
    attr_reader :listView
    attr_reader :menubar
    attr_reader :statusbar

    def setupUi(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.setObjectName("mainWindow")
    @centralwidget = Qt::Widget.new(mainWindow)
    @centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    @pushButton = Qt::PushButton.new(@centralwidget)
    @pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    @pushButton.setGeometry(Qt::Rect.new(10, 10, 75, 23))
    @listView = Qt::ListView.new(@centralwidget)
    @listView.setObjectName("listView")
    @listView.setGeometry(Qt::Rect.new(10, 40, 431, 192))
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(@centralwidget)
    @menubar = Qt::MenuBar.new(mainWindow)
    @menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    @menubar.setGeometry(Qt::Rect.new(0, 0, 451, 21))
    mainWindow.setMenuBar(@menubar)
    @statusbar = Qt::StatusBar.new(mainWindow)
    @statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    mainWindow.setStatusBar(@statusbar)

    retranslateUi(mainWindow)

    size = Qt::Size.new(451, 276)
    size = size.expandedTo(mainWindow.minimumSizeHint())
    mainWindow.resize(size)


    Qt::MetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)
    end # setupUi

    def setup_ui(mainWindow)
        setupUi(mainWindow)
    end

    def retranslateUi(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle(Qt::Application.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", nil, Qt::Application::UnicodeUTF8))
    @pushButton.setText(Qt::Application.translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", nil, Qt::Application::UnicodeUTF8))
    end # retranslateUi

    def retranslate_ui(mainWindow)
        retranslateUi(mainWindow)
    end

end

module Ui
    class MainWindow < Ui_MainWindow
    end
end  # module Ui
```

The major idea is to create a Ruby-Qt application, to run my small Ruby apps with GUI - as for now I don't need all the power of Qt library.

I'm aware of [this](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/RubyGUIProject/index.html) great example, but it shows off a different generated code for the .ui file. Or did they managed to alter it somehow? Anyway, their example works fine, while I can't make my own working properly.

I just don't know what to do with my generated file, how to go further and make a connection with my Ruby program... Maybe my `rbuic4` is wrong? Or am I'm running it with incorrect options (I'm an `-o` option) to get the [arachnoid](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/RubyGUIProject/index.html)-like template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Ok. As far as I cannot find the exact use of the mentioned generated file, I decided to copy-paste component init. code to another Ruby-Qt template app, where's everything is clear for me. Thus QtDesigner and `rbui4` are only useful for quick form design/translation, which should be then followed by all required manual polishing.

Waiting for newer version of `rbuic4` and QtRuby support of urgent version of Qt.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to actually DO something with your code is to regenerate it like this:

```
rbuic4 -x stackover.ui -o stackover.ui.rb
```

Than run the generated stackover.ui.rb file like this:

```
ruby stackover.ui.rb
```

Hope it helps.